# Set delimiter between short title–year citations in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

Biblatex provides a `\nameyeardelim` command for setting the delimiter in name–year citations.  I use this as follows to add a comma:

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

I need to cite some references which have neither an author nor an editor.  In this case Biblatex defaults to using the title (or `shorttitle`) and year, which is fine, except that there doesn't seem to be any way of setting the delimiter.  (There's no corresponding `\titleyeardelim` or `\shorttitleyeardelim` command.)

Can someone tell me what I need to do so that the following minimal working example produces "(*Proceedings of SENSEVAL-3*, 2004)" instead of "(*Proceedings of SENSEVAL-3* 2004)"?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@Proceedings{senseval2004,
  title = {Proceedings of SENSEVAL-3, the Third International Workshop on the Evaluation of Systems for the Semantic Analysis of Text},
  shorttitle = {Proceedings of SENSEVAL-3},
  year = {2004},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\autocite{senseval2004}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{nonameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Proceedings{senseval2004,
  title = {Proceedings of SENSEVAL-3, the Third International Workshop on the Evaluation of Systems for the Semantic Analysis of Text},
  shorttitle = {Proceedings of SENSEVAL-3},
  year = {2004},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nonameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}


\begin{document}
\autocite{senseval2004,sigfridsson,kant:kpv}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

*This answer was edited with a much simpler solution for newer `biblatex` versions. If you are using an ancient version of `biblatex` and the above does not work for you, consider an update. And if you can't update, have a look at the edit history for a solution that should work with older versions as well.*